# Scraping an infinite scroll website using scrapy?

Tags: python, html, json, selenium, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape records from this website https://www.heritagefuneral.com/obituaries/
it is using an infinite scroll, but is making ajax request which returns json data. Inside the json data is one key value which is 'html': "< all html code >" They literally put all the html code in the json response.So I guess my question is how would I go about parsing the json data then grabbing the information needed from the html tags?
I'm currently trying to use scrapy and selenium.

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html#handling-different-response-formats

Comment: Perfect thank you!!!